# Reference a table column by variable

Tags: excel, vba

This should be simple, but I'm a VBA noob.  I've read lots of forums, and found nothing but overly complicated code that I couldn't decipher to fit my application.

In Excel 2007 I have a Table already defined.  I can't post a picture because I am new to the forum, but the table has 3 columns, with header rows named 1 through 3, and one data row as crudely shown below:

```
Table1
+------+------+-------+
|1     |  2   |   3   |
+------+------+-------+
|Alpha |Bravo |Charlie|
+------+------+-------+
```

With this simple Table the following works, and returns the text "Alpha".

```
Sub works()

    Dim item As String

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    item = ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[1]")
    MsgBox (item)

End Sub
```

But I want to be able to refer to table column headers with an adjustable variable.  Why doesn't this work:

```
Sub doesntwork()

    Dim item As String
    Dim i As String

    i = 1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    item = ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[i]")
    MsgBox (item)

End Sub
```

It's got to be a syntax thing, but I'm having no luck sorting through all the various iterations of VBA syntax in the last 10+ years...

Please help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refer to the Headers of a structured table then this would get you a reference to the range containing the headers:

```
Dim rng as Range    
Set rng = Activesheet.Range("Table1[#Headers]")
```

...and if you want to refer to a specific header by position:

```
Dim rngHdr2    
Set rngHdr2 = rng.Cells(2) '2nd header cell
```

Comment: And this is the solution to the next step I'm going to take.  Thanks for thinking ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use concatenation to build the table name as a string:

```
item = ActiveSheet.Range("Table1[" & i & "]")
```

Comment: So THAT's what the ampersand is for!  I thought some people were using it to indicate a variable in older versions.  That was the solution I needed!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

combining both answers

Sub Demo()

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim celda As Range
Dim nroTabla As Integer
Dim nroFila  As Integer
Dim nroCol   As Integer

nroTabla = 1
nroFila = 2
nroCol = 3

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Tabla" & nroTabla & "[#Headers]")
Set celda = rng.Cells(nroFila, nroCol)

celda.Value = 700
```

End Sub